# android studio emulator not showing app

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and need some help with the emulator. Whenever I load up the emulator it automatically goes to the home screen instead of launching my app. It boots up normally:

```
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

and I've tried using the solution online of changing the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

but the emulator still doesn't show my app. I even tried downloading other projects online to see if they would load properly on my emulator and they don't seem to work as well. There doesn't seem to be any errors with my code either.

Comment: Post log cat error messages, mean while try few steps . Make sure to clean the project by going to "Build -> clean project", try creating different make model emulator.